# Google Cloud Dataflow with Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow

Trying to implement an easier form of [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/blob/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples/dataflow_python_examples/data_ingestion.py) example I have and error while insert data to BigQuery

This is the code

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import argparse
import logging
import re
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions


class DataIngestion:
    def parse_method(self, string_input):
        values = re.split(",",re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub(u'"', '', string_input)))
        row = dict(zip('Mensaje',values))
        return row



def run(argv=None):
    """The main function which creates the pipeline and runs it."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '--input', dest='input', required=False,
        help='Input file to read.  This can be a local file or '
             'a file in a Google Storage Bucket.',
        default='C:\XXXX\prueba.csv')

    parser.add_argument('--output', dest='output', required=False,
                        help='Output BQ table to write results to.',
                        default='PruebasIoT.TablaIoT')

    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

    data_ingestion = DataIngestion()

    p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))

    (p
     | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input,
                                                  skip_header_lines=1)

     | 'String To BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(lambda s:
                                            data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
                beam.io.BigQuerySink
                    (
                    known_args.output,
                    schema='Mensaje:STRING'
                 )
            )
     )
    p.run().wait_until_finish()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

And this is the error:

```
RuntimeError: Could not successfully insert rows to BigQuery table [XXX]. Errors: [<InsertErrorsValueListEntry
 errors: [<ErrorProto
 debugInfo: u''
 location: u'm'
 message: u'no such field.'
 reason: u'invalid'>]
 index: 0>, <InsertErrorsValueListEntry
 errors: [<ErrorProto
 debugInfo: u''
 location: u'm'
 message: u'no such field.'
 reason: u'invalid'>]
 index: 1>]
```

I'm new with python and maybe the solutions is quite simple, but how I could do it?

It would be possible to pass a single string in *String To BigQuery Row* instead of

```
'String To BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(lambda s:
                                        data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
```

This would be the easier way to start better than using csv files and have to translate the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you have an input CSV file with a single column, of the form:

```
Message
This is a message
This is another message
I am writing to BQ
```

If my understanding was correct, you do not need to have the `parse_method()` method, because as explained in [the sample you shared](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/blob/master/examples/dataflow-python-examples/dataflow_python_examples/data_ingestion.py), this is just a helper method that maps the CSV values to dictionaries (which are accepted by `beam.io.BigQuerySink`).

Then, you can simply do something like:

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions(pipeline_args))

(p
 | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input, skip_header_lines=1)
 | 'String To BigQuery Row' >> beam.Map(lambda s: dict(Message = s))
 | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.Write(
    beam.io.BigQuerySink(known_args.output, schema='Message:STRING')))

p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Note that the only relevant difference is that the "*String to BigQuery Row*" mapping does not need a complex method anymore, and all it does is create a Python dictionary like `{Message: "This is a message"}`, where `Message` is the name of the column in your BQ table. In this mapping, `s` is each of the String elements read in the `beam.io.ReadFromText` transform, and we apply a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

To solve using a CSV file with only one value per row I have to use this:

```
    values = re.split(",",re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub(u'"', '', string_input)))
    row = dict(zip(('Name',),values))
```

I dont know why I have to put the "," after the 'Name' but if I don't do it, the dict(zip(... doesnt work properly